# Nest custom name on serializable dto

Tags: javascript, axios, nestjs

How can I change the name of request values when using nestjs HttpModule (that uses axios)?

DTO Example:

```js
export class UserRequest {
    firstName: string;
}
```

But the API expects `first_name` as key in the json.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer) package.  It contains an `@Expose` decorator that you can decorate your properties and provide a name to expose the property as.

```js
import { serialize, Expose } from "class-transformer";

export class UserRequest {
  @Expose({ name: "first_name" })
  firstName: string;
}

const userRequest: UserRequest = new UserRequest();
userRequest.firstName = "John";

const serializedRequest = serialize(userRequest);
console.log(serializedRequest);
```

The above will produce a serialized json string as....

```json
{
  "first_name":"John"
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-transformer-expose-b1pis7

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization

https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer